# How to check only the first two letters from a mysql cell?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check a row in an mysql table for the username in php, if the username starts with ab to write an text.

the username is in a cell and looks like this: ab_12345453.

Thanks,
Sebastian

EDIT:

thank you all for your reply.
but i need something else.
i need this for joomla, i don't need to make an query, i just use: `$user->username` and i get the logged in username.

so i have the logged in username in a variable. how can i check that the username starts with ab_ ?

thank you again and sorry for the confusion :(

Comment: for me this looks like, you have a column which holds two values, ab and 12345453, which if you can should be avoided. better use another column. might lead to troubles in the future ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I vote for Artefacto's solution, and add to it a recommendation:

```
alter table bar add key(username(2));
```

In case you don't have an index for the column.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * FROM bar B where B.username LIKE 'ab%';
```

See the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE command with single % wildcard to say anychar

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE 'ab%';`

Answer (score 0):

use can use also substring

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring